# Adding to git library functionality without forking

Tags: javascript, reactjs, git

I'm trying to use a chessboard library from git and customise some of the functionality. But I don't want to edit the git library itself but still add to its functionality. So instead, I want to create a function in my own code that adds this additiona functionality. But I am not sure how I get that to work.

e.g. I am starting my function as below:

```
function showTextOverSquare() {
    const textElement = Svg.addElement('test', 'text', {
      class: cssClass,
      x: x,
      y: y,
      style: `font-size: ${this.scalingY * 10}px`,
    });
  }
```

The functions contents are taken from the git library, But since it is in my own code, I am not sure how to get it to link in because Svg for example is declared in the git library. Any pointers on what to do? Is this even possible if the javascript library is not using the export keyword on many of their functions?

I'm using React and JavaScript for my app.

Here is a link to some of the git library code:

[Example git library code](https://github.com/shaack/cm-chessboard/blob/master/src/cm-chessboard/ChessboardView.js)

Comment: It all depends on what the library code actually looks like.

Comment: I've just linked to a sample of the library code.

Comment: If you want to add a method to a class that is exported, you can add your function as a property on the prototype object for the class.

Comment: You keep referring to "a git library", but really, this has nothing to do with git - that's just how the author of the library has chosen to keep track of the changes as they work on it. Your actual question would be completely unchanged if you'd just found this Javascript code typed up on someone's blog.

Comment: My thinking is that the git repository gets updated periodically, while code on a blog page does not. Consequently, if I want the latest version of the chessboard I have to update to the latest code on git.